# Fast bi-directional hash of two integers in C

Tags: c, linux, module, kernel

I am writing a Linux kernel module and I need to come up with a hashing function that takes two integers for input. Because the code runs in kernel space, none of the standard libraries are available to me.

Basically, I need a hashing function where:

```
hash(a, b) = c
hash(b, a) = c
```

Where acceptable inputs for a and b are unsigned 32-bit integers. The hashing function should return an unsigned 64-bit integer. Collision (i.e. hash(a, b) = c and hash(d, f) = c as well) is not desirable as these values will be used in a binary search tree. The result of the search is a linked list of possible results that is then iterated over where a and b are actually compared. So some collision is acceptable, but the less collisions, the less iterations required, and the faster it will run.

Performance is also of extreme importance, this lookup will be used for every packet received in a system as I am writing a firewall application (the integers are actually packet source and destination addresses). This function is used to lookup existing network sessions.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: maybe I'm misunderstanding what you want, but why not do a bitwise OR of the smaller of the two values with the left shift 32 of the larger value. Then you utilize the full space of the 64 bits (which you don't get with simply adding).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Pseudocode of how you can do it:

```
if a>b
  return (a << 32) | b;
else 
  return (b << 32) | a;
```

This satisfies hash(a,b) == hash(b,a), utilizes the full 64 bit space, and shouldn't have collisions ...I think :)

Be careful to not directly shift the 32bit variables. Use intermediate 64-bit buffers or inline casts instead:

```
uint64_t myhash(uint32_t a, uint32_t b)
{
    uint64 a64 = (uint64_t) a;
    uint64 b64 = (uint64_t) b;
    return (a > b) ? ((a64 << 32) | b64) : ((b64 << 32) | a64);
}
```

Comment: Looks like we all like this one!

Comment: After benchmarking and testing all of the provided answers, this one appears to be both the simplest and fastest. Thank you!

Comment: Also... any way to get rid of "warning: left shift count >= width of type [enabled by default]"?

Comment: Eh, I just decided to cast the left hand to __u64 and the warning went away.

Comment: @Claudix - thanks for the edit. My c is rusty after many years using other languages (which is why I used psuedocode). The ternary operator you added in your edit is also a good addition.

Answer (score 3):

```
((a | b) << 32) + (a & b)
```

is commutative and should lead to a minimum number of collisions.
I have to think more about it though ...

Comment: Need some parentheses? `((a | b) << 32) + (a & b)`

Comment: This appears to work well, but is slightly slower than the solution hatchet posted after testing.

Answer (score 3):

```
#define MYHASH(a,b) ( (((UINT64) max(a,b)) << 32) | ((UINT64) min(a,b)) )
```

Comment: This looks like a good solution!  Using this macro, though, will cause 'a' and 'b' to be silently evaluated twice (or more, depending on the definitions of 'max' and 'min'), which could cause unexpected behaviors.  Also, on Stack Overflow we usually discourage code-only answers like this: see http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/95473.  I (and probably many other readers) can see and understand how and why this works, but the OP and other readers could benefit from a little explanation on why and how this works.

Answer (score 1):

How about `((uint64_t)max(a, b) << UINT64_C(32)) | (uint64_t)min(a, b))`? This would avoid collisions entirely, as there is no possible overlap between inputs. I can't speak to the distribution though, as that depends on your input values.

Comment: A first-time poster beat you to this solution by 3 minutes: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11786819  though they didn't have as much background info...

Comment: Yeah, I saw that immediately after I posted. Not sure what protocol is in this case...

Comment: Unfortunately I do not have uint64_t, max, UINT64_C, or min types/functions available to me. I am using __s64 and __u32 in the linux/types.h header.

Comment: I'm sure you can figure out the equivalents to use. As for `max`/`min`, they're not part of the C standard library but they're very easy to implement.

Answer (score 1):

(a ^ b)  | ((a ^ ~b) <<32);

Comment: @wildplasser - It's not complete nonsense, it's branch-free code which is a great thing in many situations.  It does take more arithmetic operations than other solutions which just do a compare and shift, but those are always really fast. All that it needs to compile properly is `uint64_t hash =` at the start, and all that it needs to be a great answer is an explanation of when this will produce a better distribution than those methods.

Comment: Works fine, but is slightly slower than the solution hatchet posted.

Comment: It is completely rubbish, because it wastes 32 bits, because upper 32 bits and lower 32 bits are complementary, wasting 32/64 bits. BTW: Thats a good reason to test hash-functions for *spread*, not performance

Comment: @wildplasser - No, they're not complementary: Because the inversion is applied to only `b` in the upper 32 bits, they're different depending on the ordering of a and b.

Comment: ..., but you can predict the value of bit x, given the value of bit x +- 32. But it still *is* symmetric ... (I am going to cry myself to sleep, reading Knuth 4a ...)